# How do I access a variable value set by me in environment variables under system properties?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I created a new variable "sam" under system environment variables for current account and gave it a value as: "D:/My_folder/files/items". I need to fetch this path using python code. How can I do this? The code snippet below just returns my home directory:

```
print(os.environ['HOME'])
```

Comment: print(os.environ['sam'])  may work

Answer (score 0):

You can access Environment variables directly through os.environ to get complete list:

```
print(os.environ)
```

To access a specific path you need to enter a key from the path, just any word that exists in it. In your case, you can use "My_folder" for example. As follows:

```
print(os.environ['My_folder'])
```

Comment: In this way we can access system variables, I want to access user variables which are found above system variables. Can you tell how to do  that?